# rest server centos 7 and python 3 doesnt seem work well

Tags: linux, python-3.x, rest, centos7

I have a rest server that i use it in the my main program ; rest server is running on centos 7 vps when i run the main on my laptop which is windows 7 it works as well; but when i run the main as a service on the same vps server it doesn't work well i've checked every single possible problems even changing unicode but i wouldn't find a solution yet.

here is my rest server code:

```
from bottle import route, run, redirect
import sqlite3

db = sqlite3.connect("checkLink.db")
db.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS checkLink")
db.execute("CREATE TABLE checkLink(user_id INT, link TEXT, join_link TEXT, 
check_id INT)")
db.execute("CREATE UNIQUE INDEX user_id ON checkLink(user_id, link, 
join_link, check_id)")
db.commit()


def database(user_id, link):
  db2 = sqlite3.connect("checkLink.db")
  db2.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
  cursor = db2.execute("SELECT * FROM checkLink WHERE user_id=? AND link=?", 
  (user_id, link))
  db2.commit()
  for row in cursor:
      check_id = row["check_id"]
      if check_id == 1:
         return 1
      else:
         return 0


def database_insert(user_id, link):
    db2 = sqlite3.connect("checkLink.db")
    db2.execute("INSERT INTO checkLink(user_id, link, join_link, check_id) 
        VALUES (?,?,?,?)", (user_id, link,                                                                                    
              "http://my link", 1))
    db2.commit()


@route('/<link>/<chat_id>')
 def index(link, chat_id):
    check = database(chat_id, link)
    if check != 1:
        database_insert(chat_id, link)
        redirect("https://my link")



@route('/redirect')
 def index():
    redirect("https://my link")


@route('/check/<link>/<chat_id>')
 def index(link, chat_id):
    check = database(chat_id, link)
    if check == 1:
        return {"id": chat_id, "permission": "True"}
    else:
        return {"id": chat_id, "permission": "False"}

run(host='my ip', port=my port)
```

Comment: Do you have any log or error   information?  If   you have ,  show  it in question .

Comment: it doesn't have any error it works well but it wouldn't return true value when i run it as service or with python command in centos 7 vps it always return false in this case

Comment: but when i run rest server as service in centos 7 and run my main on my laptop which is windows 7 it works perfectly true